# Filtering an AJAX request call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an issue related to a filtered AJAX call I am making to populate a list with ZipCodes and Regions.

My JSON array that I take in from `ZipCodeService.ashx` contains the fields "Name" and "Code" and I am trying to only get the results that has "SampleCity" in the Name field. However, right now all of the fields and their data are getting returned, so the filter is obviously not working as it should or like I am expecting it to. Any help is much appreciated!

I am new to JQuery/Javascript and extremely new to AJAX, so bear with me.

**site.js**

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    method: "POST",
    url: "../ZipCodeService.ashx",
    data: { Name: "SampleCity" },
    success: function (data) {

            var $select = $('#list1');
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $('<option>',
                {
                    value: item.Code + " - " + item.Name,
                }).html(item.Code + " - " + item.Name).appendTo($select),
                '</option>';
            });

    }
});
```

**ZipCodeService.ashx**

```
public class ZipCodeService : IHttpHandler
{
    [DataContract]
    public class ZipCode
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        var p = new ZipCode[] {
            new ZipCode()
        {
            Code = "00001",
            Name = "SampleCity"
        },new ZipCode()
        {
            Code = "00002",
            Name = "SampleCity2"
        },new ZipCode()
        {
            Code = "00003",
            Name = "SampleCity3"
        },new ZipCode()
        {
            Code = "00004",
            Name = "SampleCity4"
        }
        };

        MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ZipCode[]));
        ser.WriteObject(stream1, p);

        context.Response.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream1.ToArray()));
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see a "filter" in this code. You are just appending all of the results to `#list1`

Comment: I am, without any doubt a beginner to AJAX and Jquery so I'd personally be expecting the data: {} attribute to be the filter. I guess this is not the case? @Turnip

Comment: Can you add the code of ZipCodeService.ashx? You are sending a JSON object to the page as a parameter. If the .ashx page is expecting it everything should work ok, if it's not the case, maybe you should send something different.

Comment: Shouldn't the filtering happen on server side, ie. in ***ZipCodeService.ashx*** which you are posting to? You should take parameter ***Name*** and filter by it's value.

Comment: You need to show us the contents of `ZipCodeService.ashx`. This doesn't really have anything to do with ajax or the code you have posted

Comment: @Xariez Do you want the filter happening on server side instead of client side? I can update the code if you required.

Comment: It may have to get changed to server-side later on, but at this point what matters is that it actually works in itself. @Aruna

Comment: @Xariez Okay fine and if you would like to change this in server side now, I can give you the code.

Comment: @Xariez Anyways, I have updated the server side filtering which you can use in the future when you actually need. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `if` condition for that :

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    method: "POST",
    url: "../ZipCodeService.ashx",
    data: {
        Name: "SampleCity"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var $select = $('#list1');
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            if (Item.Name == "SampleCity") {
                $select.append('<option value="' + item.Code + '">' + item.Name + '</option>');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Just got it fixed myself this way as well! I'll mark this as the answer as it is indeed the code that got it fixed.

Comment: @Xariez Don't you want the filter happening on server side instead of client side?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the filtering in client side, you can try Surjeet's solution.

But if you need to do the same in server side as you already sent a input data, you can try the below.

I have used [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) to serialize the incoming data and you can add a namespace for this `System.Web.Script.Serialization` with the reference to the assembly `System.Web.Extensions.dll`.

```
public class ZipCodeService : IHttpHandler
{
    [DataContract]
    public class ZipCode
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Zip
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        var p = new ZipCode[] {
            new ZipCode()
        {
            Code = "00001",
            Name = "SampleCity"
        },new ZipCode()
        {
            Code = "00002",
            Name = "SampleCity2"
        },new ZipCode()
        {
            Code = "00003",
            Name = "SampleCity3"
        },new ZipCode()
        {
            Code = "00004",
            Name = "SampleCity4"
        }
        };

        var sr = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream);
        var stream = sr.ReadToEnd();    
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var postedData = serializer.Deserialize<Zip>(stream); 

        var filtered = p.Where(z => z.Name == postedData.Name).ToArray(); 

        MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ZipCode[]));
        ser.WriteObject(stream1, filtered);

        context.Response.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream1.ToArray()));
    }

}
```